# Refreshing a div using javascript in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

So currently I am creating approve or deny page for several users in PHP
and the page that I am building needs to be **REFRESH**

1.What I am trying to do is refreshing a SPECIFIC DIV

```
     The function refresh in javascript is working but there is
     a sudden duplication of div.
```

I checked it several times and  there is NO double(2) input="type" for search.

What line should I modify in to remove the duplicate **SEARCH** in div ref1 ?

2. Can you guys please suggest an alternative way  to refresh a div ?

[image]

```html
<style>
           #ref2{
               background-color: darkseagreen;
           } #ref1{
               background-color: pink;
           }
       </style> 
    
 <body>
        <div id="ref1">
               shortcut preview **
              PHP -> isset ....add, delete, approve, search                       
               then view the content (SELECT * FROM dbname)  
               see image ^
   </div>


   <div id="ref2">
            <form action="tor.php" method="post">
              <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search for members.." onkeydown="searchq();" required  />
              <input type="submit" value=">>">
              <?php echo("$output"); ?>
           </form>         
      </div> 

<script langauge="javascript">
    function updateContent() {
    $.get("#", function(data) 
    { 
        $("#ref1").html( data ); 
        });
    }
        setInterval(updateContent, 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to get the content of the ref1 div only to replace the previous content with, as you now get the entire HTML page and replace the div content with it.

```
function updateContent() {
   $.get("#", function(data) 
   {
    var x = document.createElement("div"); 
        x.innerHTML = data;
       $("#ref1").html( $(x).find("#ref1").html()); 
    });
}
    setInterval(updateContent, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Message to myself is to use AJAX or better create an API.

Comment: Is this an answer?

Comment: yes. Because I remember 1 yr and 9 months ago that I wanted to see the updates asap. I am not doing this project anymore that's why I can't post the code